# How come Unity's StartCoroutine work with and without assignment?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried searching but was lost between all the threads that explain the co-routine system but not this detail. I already know that `StartCoroutine` returns a Co-routine, so I tried looking if there's some sort of implicit operator overloading for a void return type and even tried it, but it didn't work and I found nothing. That's honestly all I could think of, you can tell i'm a beginner
There's no specific goal of this question, i'm just really interested. thanks in advance

Edit :I apologize for not making my question clear :
How can say both `StartCoroutine(example());` and `Coroutine myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(example())` ? How does the first one work like a void if the return type is Coroutine ?

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out what you are asking here. Can you give a code sample that illustrates what is confusing you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Compare

```
StartCoroutine(example());
```

> and

```
Coroutine myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(example());
```

> How does the first one work like a `void` if the return type is `Coroutine` ?

You've got the rule backwards in your head. The rule in C# is not "A non-void method must have its returned value assigned or used."  The rule is the opposite: a void method can only be used as a statement.

If you use a non-void method as a statement, the compiler generates code which discards the returned value.

Whether that is a *smart* thing to do or not is not for the compiler to decide.

However, it *is* the case that only *certain* expressions may be used as statements; unsurprisngly, they are those expressions which are useful for their side effects. They are:

- method calls
- assignments (yes, assignments are expressions)
- increments / decrements
- constructor invocations ("new") -- this is rare
- awaits

So you can say:

```
M();
x = 123;
x++;
new Abc();
await someTask;
```

But not

```
2 + 2;
(string)M();
```

and so on.

Comment: Eric, I don't know if you do Unity3d or not but just want to give you a heads up that Unity runs on .NET 2.0 PCL with some 3.5 niceties like Linq thrown in. So you can't use async/await in it (Still upvoted your answer, because it is very good, just did not not want you to focus on async/await too much for a unity3d question).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Good point, thanks!  Too bad about that, as obviously await makes dealing with coroutines much easier.

Comment: Unity stole the auto implemented iterators of `yield return` to do it instead because it came out long before C#5. I am hoping that when they swich over to netstandard they start allowing us to use async/await instead of yield returning special [`YieldInstruction`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/YieldInstruction.html) derived classes.

Comment: Actually saving the coroutine returned object has little purpose since Coroutine has no public member. Even Start/StopCoroutine takes IEnumerator as parameter so there is really little you could do with it. Most likely you would do IEnumerator enu = example(); so you have a reference to IEnumerator you can play with.

Answer (score 3):

You don't always need to save the result of a function that has a return value. If you did

```
public void Awake()
{
    Foo();
}

private int Foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

The compiler would have no problem with it.

The reason `StartCoroutine` returns anything is if you wanted to do nested Coroutines and you wanted to wait for the inner routine to finish before continuing with the outer.

Here is a example where rooms get loaded dynamically in a game, once the first room is loaded the player is allowed to move then the additional rooms get loaded sequentially afterward.

```
private bool _allowPlayerMovement;

public Room FirstRoom;
public Room SecondRoom;
public Room ThirdRoom;
//...

public void Awake()
{
    _allowPlayerMovement = false;
    StartCoroutine(LoadRooms())
}

private IEnumerator LoadRooms()
{
    //Runs the LoadFirstRoom Coroutine then waits for it to finish.
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadFirstRoom())

    //One the first routine finishes set the variable to true.
    _allowPlayerMovement = true;

    //Start loading the 2nd room, wait for it to finish
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadSecondRoom())

    //Once the 2nd room is finished loading start loading the 3rd room.
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadThirdRoom())

   //... And so on
}

private IEnumerator LoadFirstRoom()
{
   WWW www = new WWW("http:\\example.com\levels\FirstRoom.json")
   yield return www;
   FirstRoom = JsonUtility.FromJson<Room>(www.text);
}

//... And so on
```

If you don't care about when the Coroutine "finishes" there is no need to save the result from `StartCoroutine` (like in the `Awake` function of my above example)

Comment: "If you don't care about when the Coroutine "finishes" there is no need to save the result from StartCoroutine" It think that's what the OP is looking for

Comment: @Programmer I think so too, I just wanted to include a example of when you would care that it finishes too.

Comment: Thanks, Scott ! I actually realise that and have been using coroutines both ways, just interested in the fact I just learned : that expressions can be used as statements. I thought it needed some special implementatin kinda like implicit operator overloading, but all is clear now, thanks !